# Initializing templated matrix class with unique pointer member to vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, member, unique-ptr

I have

```
template<class T>
class Matrix{
public:
Matrix();
~Matrix();

private:
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<T> > > PtrToMyMatrix;

};
```

I have difficulty with initializing `PtrToMyMatrix`. Suppose that the constructor should only put in `PtrToMyMatrix` a pointer to a 1x1 matrix of a T. How do I write this?

I suppose it is something like

```
Matrix<T>::Matrix():PtrToMyMatrix(//Here it goes the value
){};
```

In the place of the value I suppose it should go something like

```
new std::unique_ptr<vector<vector<T> > >(// Here a new matrix
)
```

In the place of the new matrix I suppose it goes something like

```
new vector<vector<T> >(// Here a new vector
)
```

In the place of the new vector

```
new vector<T>(new T())
```

How should it be?

Comment: This looks like there are two indirections too many. Is there a reason why you don't just use a single `vector` directly as a data member?

Comment: @dyp My reason might be unfounded since I am a beginner, but my reason is that I wanted to make it easy to move the content of the matrix from one to another.

Comment: @Karene are you using c++11 or c++03?

Comment: @owensss Look at that `unique_ptr`.

Comment: Please, always a `;` after a class definition... ;-)

Comment: @Karene That's what *move semantics* has been introduced for in C++11. `vector<T>` can be efficiently moved itself. Unless you want/need to efficiently move single matrix columns/rows, a single `vector<T>` will probably be better.

Comment: A `unique_ptr` takes a pointer to the resource that it will own. The type of `PtrToMyMatrix` says that it will own a multi-dimensional vector. Therefore when initializing the pointer, you can pass it a pointer to a vector of vectors.

Comment: @dyp Yes, I was asked to write a matrix class that used move semantics. I wasn't sure if vector had a move. I will check that out.

Comment: In C++14 there is `make_unique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're after this:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::vector<T> > >
    PtrToMyMatrix(new std::vector<std::vector<T> >(1, std::vector<T>(1)));
```

The constructor is `std::vector(size_type n, const value_type& val);` (alloc missing).

So you construct the outer `vector` with `1` inner `vector` that is constructed with `1` `T`.

However it is very rarely necessary to create `std::vector` dynamically as it already stors its internal data dynamically. You would usually just instantiate it by value:

```
std::vector<std::vector<T> > MyMatrix(1, std::vector<T>(1));
```

Comment: This works. Now I have to understand it. Give me a few minutes to do so and accept your answer.

Comment: @Karene if you understand just how to initialize a vector of vectors then this is not a big step up;   e.g. `vector<vector<T>> vec(1, vector<T>(1));`

Comment: I think my main confusion was that I thought that to `PtrToMyMatrix`, which is a unique_ptr I should pass it a unique_ptr in the initialization. You can see I was trying to do so above in the question.